# Nesting a Wordpress post loop inside a page loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Making a one-page Wordpress theme. Using this loop to call all pages and display them as sections (html5  tags):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'page' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'asc'
);
query_posts( $args );

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <section id="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" class="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">
        <div class="inner clearfix">
            <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
        </div>
    </section> 
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p>Sorry, no pages matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This creates a nice little loop of sections based on pages. My only concern is: one of these "pages" / sections should show a few blog posts. Looking for a way to essentially create a loop inside a loop -- which can be reordered along with the pages.

So I guess my question is:

- What might this code look like?
- Would it be completely wrong to put this code inside the text editor inside the wordpress page editor? This seems wrong, but I can't think of another way.

Thanks!

Comment: [Check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops).

Comment: Thank you @SheikhHeera -- I hadn't even thought of that. That code put into a shortcode might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has this functionality built-in. See [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops).